# Is it possible to get session variables and call API in Laravel view composer?

Tags: laravel, api, session, request, composer-php

In AppServiceProvider.php, I am trying to get data from session then call API with it then pass a variable after getting it from the response.

Also, I don't know if it's right. I added "Request $request" to boot function as in other parts of code.

And the error I'm getting is "RuntimeException in Request.php line 388: Session store not set on request." Does that mean session variable isn't set? I would've thought they'd be available after I log in to my site as I session put "token" and "member_id" during login.

Is it because view controller is higher level so my session puts during login won't come before bootstrap code in boot function here uses them? Oh, or is the request not really passed in as parameter of boot function as I would've liked it to. How would I otherwise do that or get variables from the session?

Anyway, are the steps I'm taking proper? If I'm doing things incorrectly throughout, such as bad practice, please point it out as well thanks.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $params = array(
            'token' => $request->session()->get('token'),
            'member_id' => $request->session()->get('member_id'),
            'activity' => 'GET MEMBER INFO'
        );

        $response = $client->request('POST',
            env('SPACE_4_CAR_API_DOMAIN') . 'select_api/GetMemberInfo.php',
            ['json' => $params]
        );

        $returnData = json_decode($response->getBody());

        view()->composer('layout', function ($view) {
            $view->with('is_admin', $returnData->is_administrator);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Laravel session is initialized in a middleware so you can't access the session from a Service Provider, because they execute before the middleware in the request lifecycle. Also the `boot` function does not have any parameter, so your request is most probably null there.

Comment: @nakov Is there then a way to access the session or store it somewhere earlier in request lifecycle?

Comment: You can create a custom middleware, and use the session there.